# can you modify divs on external html file

Tags: jquery, html

I have an index.html file that has three frames: top.html (which will include the title of the page", left.html (which will include jstree nodes" and right.html, that will include 6 divs to show images based on the node selected on the left.html. If I want to store my tree nodes on the left.html frame and selecting a node on the left, I like to load the image on the divs stored on the right.html file. Is this doable?

This is teh script that does the loading of the jstree nodes and selecting nodes. This works if all the divs are on one index.html file.
script.js -- this works when all the divs are on one page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#left").jstree({  

         "xml_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {  

                 "url" : "tree.xml" 

             },  

             "xsl" : "nest"

         },  


         "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"] 

}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
$("#left").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);

    img1 = new Image;
    img1.src=teamA.jpeg;
    var node_id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    if (node_id=="teamA" {
    $("#first").html(img1).css("border","1px solid");
}
```

Comment: If they are all on the same domain, it is definitely doable. Why are you using iframes for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside of the frame: With

```
parent.document
```

you can access the parent frame (in this case the index containing the 3 frames) and then access its children (frames) via normal ID selectors:

```
$('#right').contents();
```

Comment: Peter, Im very new to jquery. I have index.html file as parent, left.html (holding my jstree) and right.html (holding my divs). You are saying within the script.js, I can do this: $('#right').contents().("#first").html(img1).css("border","1px solid")?

Comment: @MikeDude it would be `.contents().find("#first").etc()`

Comment: @kevin, I have this:  $('#right').contents().find('#first').html(img1).css("border","1px solid"); not working

Comment: @MikeDude I would have to see it in action, that isn't something i can easily test in a jsfiddle.

Comment: does anybody else have any input on this?

Comment: I can update the frames by some text but not the divs inside the frames. This works: $('#right').html('this is a test'); but when try to do this, not working: $('#right').contents().find('#first').html("this is a test");